# Phone Number Validation in C++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Contact.h"

using namespace std;

using namespace sict;

int main()

{

cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;

cout << "Testing the default constructor!" << endl;
cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
sict::Contact empty; // sict:: intentional
empty.display();
cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "Testing an invalid contact!" << endl;
cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
Contact bad(nullptr, nullptr, 0);
bad.display();
Contact alsoBad("", nullptr, 0);
alsoBad.display();
cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "Testing the constructor with parameters!" << endl;
cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
Contact temp("A very long name for contact!", nullptr, 0);
temp.display();
cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "Testing a valid contact!" << endl;
cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
long long phoneNumbers[] = { 1416123456LL, // invalid: no country code
                               14161234567LL,
                             1416234567890LL, // invalid: wrong country code
                               14162345678LL,
                               10162345678LL, // invalid: wrong area code
                                        -1LL, // invalid: all components are wrong
                              124163456789LL,
                               14160345678LL, // invalid: wrong phone component
                               14161230002LL
};
Contact someContact("John Doe", phoneNumbers, 9);
someContact.display();
cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I have been given this piece of code and i have to use a function to check if the phone numbers inside "long long phoneNumbers[]" are valid.

**Following needs should be met for the phone number to be valid:**

A valid phone number has one or two digits for the country code (cannot be zero)

Has exactly three digits for the area code (cannot start with zero)

and has exactly even digits for the number (cannot start with zero);

I am having difficulty in breaking down the code into sections for area code, country code and the main phone number due to which i cannot validate the phone number.

Thanks for anyone helping!

Comment: Turn it into a string and then just go through each character at a time?

Comment: "cannot start with zero" is actually guaranteed by representing your phone numbers as integers.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please read [ask]

Comment: As @alterigel mentioned by representing your phone numbers as `long long` you can not complain if a phone number started with 0. You threw away that information.

Comment: Like post codes, phone numbers should be a string data type.

Comment: Such validation seems easy to get wrong, since, just like with time zones, your validation, might be wrong, somewhere.

Comment: Implementing correct phone number parsing is very hard. I would recommend not doing it yourself and deferring to [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber).

Comment: None of my phone numbers passes your validation. May as well just drop the country code because only a few countries have the scheme you describe.

Comment: My advice is 1. change your phone numbers to `std::string` because `long long` is not able to validate numbers starting with 0 (integers do not store/retain leading 0s). 2. create a function to validate a phone number. something like `bool isValidPhoneNumber(std::string)` and test this function alone. It does not need any of the rest of your program to test this one function. 3. Debug (step through the algorithm line by line looking at your variables at each step) your function when you find failures.

Comment: even digits or eleven digits?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 approaches:

1. convert the phone number to a string, and then simply iterate over it.
2. Separate the phone number as an integer to multiple numbers. For example, if you want to get the last 2 digits of a number, you'll do this:

   ```
   last_2_digits = original_number % 100;
   ```

Good luck with that~